# Javascript regular expressions html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can get text like this `text example` if I wrote `<font size="50"> text example </font>`using regular expressions in **Javascript** or **jQuery**.

For example:
If I in

```
     var x = window.prompt("Edit this text: ",messageText.getText());
```

type

```
    <font size="50"> Font 50 </font>
```

I want to output of

```
console.log(x)
```

be just a Font 50 without  tags.

Thank you

Comment: I suggest you explain with a little more detail, you question as it is does not make much sense and will probably get downvoted.

Comment: Why do you need to use regular expressions for this?  JavaScript (and jQuery) has functionality for extracting content from DOM elements.  In the example given, `$('font').text()` would extract what you want.  For more complex markup, change the selector accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the following html

```
<div>Random content can go <font size="50">here</font> with forn elements
<font size="50">mixed into the text</font>, in random positions.</div>
```

Retrieve text as below

```
//first get all elements with the appropriate selector
var $fontElements = $("font[size='50']");

//then access them one by one using .each(). $(this).text() gets the actual text
$fontElements.each(function (index) {
    var line = "element " + index + "=>" + $(this).text();
    $("#result1").append(line);
    $("#result1").append($("<br>"));
});

//using .text() right away will mix all the elements into one continous sting.
$("#result2").text($fontElements.text());
```

The above output will give

For result1

```
element 0=>here
element 1=>mixed into the text
```

For result2

```
heremixed into the text
```

Here is a link to jsfiddle with a working example http://jsfiddle.net/Df9h9/

Comment: you forgot text(), this will only return html object(font).

Comment: Yes of course I forgot .text() cause this will return all the selected tags, so .text() might be pretty pointless.

Comment: object you returned contain a lot more iformation about font tag, and he needs text value. Your object contain information like font properties (for example size) and many others. So text() is not pointless at all.

Comment: Here is an elaborate answer @BojanKovacevic . I believe it accommodates your request for using .text(), as well as explaining why using .text() right away might be pointless.

Comment: now it is better explained. Anyway, you conclude that he will have more font elements with same size property, and in his example that is not the case. In his example, text() is enough. But if you wanted to show him how to proceed in case more then one element are fetched, then you need to explain it like you just did. Not just put jquery selector that only contain html object. Updated answer now deserve + so ill give it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use regular expression for this - it'd be heresy and generally a bad idea.

You can use `.text()` instead:

```
alert($('<font size="50"> text example </font>').text());
```

If the element is in your DOM you can use a selector to retrieve it (note that this will match *all* font elements with this attribute):

```
alert($('font[size=50]').text());
```

Comment: console.log(getText);
 $('font').text();
console.log(getText);
I try with this but in both cases I got the same output: <font size="50"> Text </font>

Comment: you are doing something wrong. This must work. Check it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Wt6Xm/)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent).
Earlier, if one wanted to retrieve the text within a tag, there was the "innerText".
For a Discussion about the pro and cons of textContent vs innerText read the above article.
textContent is used by jQuery's [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) (sizzle.getText) if you look at the source code:

```
if ( typeof elem.textContent === "string" ) {
        return elem.textContent;
```